# Why intent is not start another activity

Tags: java, android

My LoginActivity is not starting another activity. It starts on the same page on LoginActivity.How to solve it.

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            SetValidation();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // redirect to RegisterActivity
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
}

public void SetValidation()
{
   if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean you click on one of those buttons and it doesn't start an activity? If so, which button? If it is the `login` button, have you confirmed that `isEmailValid` and `isPasswordValid` are actually true?

Comment: Preferably call the current class name (LoginActivity.this) in place of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

You apply some conditions to start an `Activity` `isEmailValid && isPasswordValid`, please check that both of them have value `true`. If one of them has value `false` the new `Activity` won't start.

If you want to start new `Activity` without any conditions:

```
public void SetValidation()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search_Activity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```